# No injective linear map from $V^*$ to $V$ for infinite dimensional $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Suppose $V$ is an infinite dimensional linear space. Show that there is no injective linear map from $V^*$ to $V$.

There is a hint that if $V$ has a basis indexed by $S$, then construct a basis of $V^*$ indexed by $2^S$. But I fail to do so. Can anyone give me some clues?

Comment: It is true that the dimension of $V^*$ is $2^\kappa$, when $V$ has infinite dimension $\kappa$; however this depends on the axiom of choice and, as far as I know, it's not possible to show an explicit basis of $V^*$ starting from a basis of $V$.

Comment: Thanks! But how to prove the dimension of $V^*$ is $2^\kappa$?

Comment: You can look at http://www.science.oregonstate.edu/~parks/sample338.pdf

Comment: @egreg The link doesn't work anymore. If you still remember the proof, would you mind giving a sketch?

Comment: @ShaVuklia https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/dualspaceinfinite.pdf The proof is elaborated from https://mathoverflow.net/a/13372

Comment: @egreg Great, thanks!